# R Markdown and Plotly: fig.align not working with HTML output

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

`fig.align` is not working with R Markdown HTML outputs and plotly and I looking for some help!

Here is a MWE:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
editor_options: 
chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align = "center")
library(plotly)
```


```{r}
plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans"),
  y = c(20, 14),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar")
```


```{r, fig.align = 'right'}
plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans"),
  y = c(20, 14),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar")
```

```{r, fig.align = 'center'}
plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans"),
 y = c(20, 14),
 name = "SF Zoo",
type = "bar")
```
````

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike normal plots, plotly graphics have a different HTML setup. What you can do is use the shiny package and wrap another div container around each plot:

```
library(shiny)
div(plot_ly(
x = c("giraffes", "orangutans"),
y = c(20, 14),
name = "SF Zoo",
type = "bar"), align = "right")
```

Comment: This almost works for me...the `plot_ly` plot is centred but spans the entire html text width (so it would be centred regardless). However the figure caption disappears when I use the above code...did that happen on yours?

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, the solution proposed above made my `plotly` plot span the entire html text width. The following worked for me without streching the plot:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
chunk_output_type: console
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.center {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

<div class = 'center'>
```{r, echo = F, message = F}
library(plotly)
plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans"),
  y = c(20, 14),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar")
```
</div>
````

For also showing the code snipped this solution is a bit ugly since the code snipped will also get centered. I use the following work-around:

````
```{r plot1, results = F, message = F}
library(plotly)
plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans"),
  y = c(20, 14),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar")
```

<div class = 'center'>
```{r plot1, echo = F}
```
</div>
````

Answer (score 0):

adding the previous explanation from Martin, I figured out another way that you might be useful:

You can add  and  just between the chunk for making plotly:

````
    <center>

    ```{r, echo = FALSE, out.width = "60%"}
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)

    plot <- iris %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_boxplot()
    
    ggplotly(plot)
    ```

    </center>
````